# Run link after code execution JavaScript

Tags: javascript, alert

I want to run `psns:` after my code has executed as a link. `psns:` will close the PlayStation 4 browser and is designed to be clicked on, but I want to automatically run it without having the user click on it.

This is what I have:

```
if(alert('The browser will now close.')) window.location.href='psns:';
```

I do get the alert, but for some odd reason the browser does not close, even though when you click a link with `psns:` as a href, it does. How can I make it so it runs `psns:` after the alert?

Comment: Try `window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();`

Comment: I specifically need to load the `psns:` URL, window.close() does not function in the PS4 browser. @Deckerz

Comment: try the first half of what i said, then execute your code. or you can create a page called closing.html which is just the `window.location.href='psns:';` in its own document and then self navigate to it and see if that works

Comment: So chave them click a link and put your onclick on the link.